# php echo json_encode from DB entries -> getting strange format. how to get a proper JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

At the moment i get the following JSON:

```
["1Sales & Consulting","2Pyments","3Investing","4Financing","5Cross Functional"]
```

but i would like to have a proper JSON like:

```
[{"id":1, "name": "Sales & Consulting"}{"id": 2, "name": "Pyments"}{"id": 3, "Investing"}{"id": 4, "name": "Financing"}{"id": 5, "name": "Cross"}]
```

The code i used to generate the first output is:

```
<?php
define('servername','localhost');
define('username','root');
define('password','');
define('dbname','integration');
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(servername, username, password, dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM capability_level1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$test = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $test[] = $row["id"] . $row["name"];
    }
    echo json_encode($test);
} else {
    echo json_encode("0 results");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

what do i have to change? this echo is needed to pass to ajax in a second step

Comment: Just `$test[] = $row;` Or immediate fetch `$test = $result->fetch_all();`.

Comment: i tried to put your first suggestion in to the while loop and it gives me an error. Then i tried it outside before the while again error then i tried your second suggestion in the while loop and there was another error message. i guess i don't get what you are suggesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the lines

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $test[] = $row["id"] . $row["name"];
}
```

to

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $test[] = array(
         'id' => $row["id"],
         'name' => $row["name"]
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just chnge the semicolon's position to after the array definition! as of the SO-Rules i cannot edit your post because it is less than 6 changes! After that it works fine, thanks

Comment: @J.Doe - Thanks for that. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
       array_push($test, $row);
 }
 echo json_encode($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code changes:-

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$test = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($test, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($test);
} else {
    echo json_encode("0 results");
}
$conn->close();

?>
```